# re.search() exact comparison at end of string

Tags: python, regex

Attempting to do an exact string comparison for the end of a string:

```
re.search(r'%s' % name1, name2, re.IGNORECASE)
```

So if `name1 = "local/foo"` and `name2= "foo"` the statement will return true.

However, the above test is returning true for `name1 = "foo"` and `name2 = "foo-bar"`
How can I match the ends only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` to anchor your search to the end:

```
re.search(r'%s$' % name1, name2, re.IGNORECASE)
```

You *probably* want to use `re.escape()` to make sure no metacharacters in `name1` are interpreted as regular expression patterns:

```
re.search(r'%s$' % re.escape(name1), name2, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: @klashxx: depends on the input, but yes, when your input can contain multiple lines and you really want to match the end of the whole input string, then `\Z` is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
name1.lower().endswith(name2.lower())
```

Comment: muuuch better than re.

Answer (score 1):

There's also `re.fullmatch` on Python 3.4. This uses `\Z` over `$`, so has a better default.